# Quick quiz using Excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to create an easy quiz in Excel that will test my daughter over periodic chart

So this is what I'm thinking:

```
Sheet1 - Quiz
--------
Silver, ???, right or wrong

Sheet2 - Answers 
--------
Silver,Au
```

Can you help me with a formula?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the quiz below by placing the Periodic Table answers on 2 sheets ("Quiz" and "Answers").  Assume the quiz answers will be in column B.  On the Quiz sheet, delete the answers in column B and replace by a formula like this dragged down the column:

`=IF(Answers!B2=Quiz!D2,"right","wrong")`

The animated gif shows 6 quiz questions being answered, 3 right, 3 wrong.

[image]

Of course, you could do a lot to improve the presentation, and you could randomize the question order using the `RAND()` function, but this gets you started.  Also, [here's a website](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/35_pt/pt_database.php?PT_id=194) with Periodic Tables in Excel form

Comment: Wow, I'm more interested in how you did the video?

Comment: Regarding the "video": It's a screen recording using QuickTime on a Mac, followed by ezgif.com/maker to convert to animated .gif.  Unfortunately, if you have Windows, QuickTime won't work to make screen recordings, but you could use PowerPoint 2013 or later